# Python Multiprocessing Synchronization Inside Processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, synchronization

I am trying to run two processes simultaneously using the multiprocessing library in Python 3.9.2. I need synchronization between the two processes, such that once the processes are started, there requires synchronization inside the process. I've written sample code to explain my goal:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import time

def process_one():
    time.sleep(5)
    # ---- WAIT FOR PROCESS TWO TO CATCH UP
    # --- SYNCHRONIZE HERE
    print(time.time())

def process_two():
    time.sleep(10)
    # --- SYNCHRONIZE HERE
    print(time.time())

def main():
    first = Process(target=process_one).start()
    second = Process(target=process_two).start()

    first.join()
    second.join()

    print('Both completed at: ', time.time())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here for instance, I understand that `process_one()` and `process_two()` start at the same time. However, inside these processes, I need synchronization between the two such that the printed `time.time()` in both processes are equal (to show that there exists synchronization inside the two processes).

I've searched through the documentation and I only came down to using `synchronizer = Barrier(2)`, passing `synchronizer` as an argument to each of my process functions, then including the line `synchronizer.wait()` in both processes functions, where I want the synchronization to match. I've tested this using my own code which requires simultaneous read from an external DAQ device and read from the serial port. The serial port initialization takes 2 seconds, so I need the DAQ device read to wait the 2 seconds but not hard-coded by `time.sleep(2)`. The `synchronizer.wait()` method did not work.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I am by no means an expert on Python multiprocessing, but to my knowledge, while providing for concurrency, there is no guarantee of synchronization.

Comment: "did not work" how so? this is the method I would use... is there only one DAQ? if there's only one serial interface, that could be a problem as well.. you can't read multiple things simultaneously from a single interface. If the DAQ itself has multiple ADC's it may have specific commands for simultaneous triggering, but would probably be handled by a single command / interface. In your toy example adding a barrier and `wait()`ing on it works fine for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Barrier` instance seems to work fine. You do, however, have a problem with your assignment to `first` and `second`: the `start` method returns `None` and consequently your subsequent calls to `join` will fail.

```python
from multiprocessing import Process, Barrier

import time

def process_one(barrier):
    time.sleep(5)
    # ---- WAIT FOR PROCESS TWO TO CATCH UP
    # --- SYNCHRONIZE HERE
    barrier.wait()
    print(time.time())

def process_two(barrier):
    time.sleep(10)
    # --- SYNCHRONIZE HERE
    barrier.wait()
    print(time.time())

def main():
    barrier = Barrier(2)
    first = Process(target=process_one, args=(barrier,))
    second = Process(target=process_two, args=(barrier,))
    first.start()
    second.start()

    first.join()
    second.join()

    print('Both completed at: ', time.time())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
1626008280.0219996
1626008280.0219996
Both completed at:  1626008280.0350006
```